# Cancel Entire EC2 Services (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there anyway that I can cancel the entire ec2 services of my AWS account.
For example : terminate all instances and release all elastic ips for ALL regions by running one cmd.

And also for terminated instances, stop them from showing in the console immediately.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to just destroy everything.  It has to be done iteratively, by region and by instance, disabling termination protection of any instances and disassocating any elastic IP addresses.

Terminated instances generally disappear from the console within 60 minutes.  There is not a way to accelerate this.